# Clear form if an input is cleared

Tags: forms, field

I've got a form on my page and there is an input called name.

I'm using autocomplete on it. When there is a name which is on the database and I select it, it autocompletes the other fields with the information from the db..

I would like to know if its possible that if the person clear the field name after the fields were filled, is it possible to clear the other fields?

Comment: Are you using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`onchange`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event to clear your other fields.

Javascript:

```
function checkAndClear() {
    //Check if our database completed field is emptied
    if(document.getElementById("myAutoCompleteField").value == "") {
        //Empty the value of some other fields
        document.getElementById("someOtherAutoFilledField").value = "";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="myAutoCompleteField" type="text" onchange="checkAndClear()" />
<input id="someOtherAutoFilledField" type="text" />
```